# Table not centering in browser, using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I can not get the tables to center in the browser. Please look at my code and let me know what needs to be changed. thanks so much. I have looked over all the internal style sheets as well as the inline that I have placed on the table tags. I have another webpage that is coded the same and is similar and I can't see any differences, it is also not centering.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Pie Crust Recipe | Pies by Grandma Reeves</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Jaeden Kimball Harris"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="'Applie pie',Filling, Delicious,'Grandma Reeves', Recipe"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Come enjoy a hot applie pie, perfect for the fall season or any season really. Straight out of Grandma Reeves kitchen!"/>

<style type="text/css" media="all">

    body{
    background-color: #FEFACB;
    background-image: url("images/lemonbackground.jpg");
    text-align:center;
    }

    h1 {
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;
    }

    h2 {
    font: 'Comic Sans', times, serif;
    color: #FDC62D;
    font-size:20px;
    }

    table{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    width:850px;
    height:800px;
    }

    td{
    vertical-align:top; padding:15px;
    }

    table.center (
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

    )

    ul {
    list-style-type:square
    }

    </style>



</head>

<body>

<table class="center">

<tr>
  <td>

<table class="center" style="width:85%;" />
    <tr>
      <td>
      <a href="piefilling.html"><img src="images/filling_smnav.gif" width="154" height="143" alt="Click here for the lemon meringue pie and filling recipes"></img></a>
      </td>
      <td>
      <a href="crust.html"><img src="images/crust_smnav.gif" width="154" height="143" alt="Click here for the flaky crust recipe"></img></a>
      </td>
      <td>
      <a href="index.html"><img src="images/sm_logo.gif" width="312" height="183" alt="Lemon Meringue Pie recipe from Grandma Reeves"></img></a>
      </td>   
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
      <p style="text-alight:center;"><img src="images/yellowbar.gif" width="636" height="8" alt="red bar"></img></p>
      <h1> Pie Crust Recipe </h1>
      <h2> Ingredients</h2>

      <ul>
        <li>2 Cups flour</li>
        <li>1 Cup Butter Flavor Crisco brand shortening</li>
        <li>1 tsp salt</li>
        <li>1 tsp sugar</li>
        <li>1/4 tsp baking powder</li>
        <li>1/3 Cup milk</li>
      </ul>
      <blockquote>
        <p> Stir until lumps are dissolved (can use a hand mixer) </p>
      </blockquote>

      <h2>Bring to a Boil</h2>
      <ul>
         <li>4 cups water</li>
         <li>2 cups sugar</li>
      </ul>

     <h2> Directions </h2>
     <p> Add all dry ingredients together.</p>
     <p>Use two knives and criss cross them to cut the Butter Flavor Crisco® into the flour mixture. Cut it into the flour until the mixture is tiny crumbs.</p>
     <p>Sprinkle milk over top of the mixture and gently fold the milk into the mixture, not handling it.</p>
     <p>Spread some flour on the counter and place 1/2 of the mixture on the flour. Lightly flour the rolling pin. Roll out thin. The secret avoid handling and try to only roll it out once.</p>
     <p>Carefully place the dough in the pie pan (folding it in 1/2 first sometimes helps)</p>
     <p>Flute the edges (pinching the edges with your thumb and index finger).</p>
     <p>Bake 400° for 10-12 minutes (until lightly brown)</p>


  </td>
    </tr>
</table>    
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding "margin: 0 auto 0 auto" inside your body css.

Comment: Side note, `<img>` elements self close. There is no `</img>`. And you have a  typo in `text-alight`, and `<table class="center" style="width:85%;" />`.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your table css:

```
table
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

fiddle, if need be:  http://jsfiddle.net/vvov1y8q/

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to not set the margin to 0 if you want to display the table in middle of the browser.

Specifically, try the following this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Pie Crust Recipe | Pies by Grandma Reeves</title>
<meta name="author" content="Jaeden Kimball Harris"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="'Applie pie',Filling, Delicious,'Grandma Reeves', Recipe"/>
<meta name="description" content="Come enjoy a hot applie pie, perfect for the fall season or any season really. Straight out of Grandma Reeves kitchen!"/>

<style type="text/css" media="all">

body{
background-color: #FEFACB;
background-image: url("images/lemonbackground.jpg");
text-align:center;
}

h1 {
font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:24px;
text-align:center;
}

h2 {
font: 'Comic Sans', times, serif;
color: #FDC62D;
font-size:20px;
}

table{
background-color:#ffffff;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
height:800px;
}

td{
vertical-align:top; padding:15px;
}

table.center (
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

)

ul {
list-style-type:square
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="center">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<table class="center" style="width:50%;margin:0 auto" />
<tr>
<td>
<a href="piefilling.html"><img src="images/filling_smnav.gif" width="154"     height="143" alt="Click here for the lemon meringue pie and filling recipes">   </img></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="crust.html"><img src="images/crust_smnav.gif" width="154" height="143" alt="Click here for the flaky crust recipe"></img></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="index.html"><img src="images/sm_logo.gif" width="312" height="183" alt="Lemon Meringue Pie recipe from Grandma Reeves"></img></a>
</td>   
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<p style="text-alight:center;"><img src="images/yellowbar.gif" width="636" height="8" alt="red bar"></img></p>
<h1> Pie Crust Recipe </h1>
<h2> Ingredients</h2>
<ul>
<li>2 Cups flour</li>
<li>1 Cup Butter Flavor Crisco brand shortening</li>
<li>1 tsp salt</li>
<li>1 tsp sugar</li>
<li>1/4 tsp baking powder</li>
<li>1/3 Cup milk</li>
</ul>
<blockquote>
<p> Stir until lumps are dissolved (can use a hand mixer) </p>
</blockquote>
<h2>Bring to a Boil</h2>
<ul>
<li>4 cups water</li>
<li>2 cups sugar</li>
</ul>

<h2> Directions </h2>
<p> Add all dry ingredients together.</p>
<p>Use two knives and criss cross them to cut the Butter Flavor Crisco® into the flour mixture. Cut it into the flour until the mixture is tiny crumbs.</p>
<p>Sprinkle milk over top of the mixture and gently fold the milk into the mixture, not handling it.</p>
<p>Spread some flour on the counter and place 1/2 of the mixture on the flour. Lightly flour the rolling pin. Roll out thin. The secret avoid handling and try to only roll it out once.</p>
<p>Carefully place the dough in the pie pan (folding it in 1/2 first sometimes helps)</p>
<p>Flute the edges (pinching the edges with your thumb and index finger).   </p>
<p>Bake 400° for 10-12 minutes (until lightly brown)</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>    
</td>
</tr>
</table>   
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this works for you.